# Exibir texto HTML em Popover do Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Criei um `Popover` provido pelo `Twitter-Bootstrap` neste `Popover` é exibido uma mensagem formatada com tags `HTML`, porém quando abro a página o texto que deveria ser formato em `HTML` esta formatado como `texto plano`, como fazer para que seja exibido formatado em HTML?

**Código do popover**

```
$("#pass_ca").popover({
    title:'A senha deve conter entre 8 e 16 caracteres, incluindo:',
    content:'<ul><li>Letras Maiusculas</li><li>Letras Minusculas</li><li>Numeros</li></ul>',
    trigger:'hover',
    placement:'right'
});
```

**Tag que possui o popover**

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" id="pass_ca">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acrescente `html: true` à definição do `popover`:

```
$("#pass_ca").popover({
    title:'A senha deve conter entre 8 e 16 caracteres, incluindo:',
    content:'<ul><li>Letras Maiusculas</li><li>Letras Minusculas</li><li>Numeros</li></ul>',
    trigger:'hover',
    placement:'right',
    html: true
});
```

Veja a [funcionar no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48n9kucq/).

O valor por `default` de `html` e falso, o que faz com que a função [`text` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/text/) seja usada para validar o texto do `popover`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativamente a inserção do `html: true` no objeto passado ao `popover` é possível inserir um atributo `data-html="true"` diretamente na tag que haverá o `popover`.

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" id="pass_ca" data-html="true">
```